# Application built in Visual studio 2013(update 5) signed with sha256RSA algorithm on windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce

We are working on an windows form application **(target framework - 3.5)** which is built in visual studio 2013 update 5 and signing algorithm is **sha256RSA**.

Before when we were on visual studio 2008, It was being installed in windows XP with same signing algorithm, but after migrating on visual studio 2013, our application needs minimum .NET framework 4.5 to be installed (which is not possible for windows xp)

I m building **click once deployment** using msbuild in Nant script and by doing so I m getting Error saying "MyApp.application : manifest may not be valid or file could not be opened".
but if I try to publish the same project with same signing algorithm from visual studio itself it is all fine even in widows XP.

I came to know that sha256RSA is suppoted in .NET 4.5 or above and for lower version I should use sha1 algorithm.

But if it is so, how can Visual studio can build such installation which can be successfully installed in an environment with .NET framework 3.5 (E.G. in windows XP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, Problem was "**mage.exe**".

Before when we were on visual studio 2008 and while building click once setup we were using mage.exe 3.5.30729.1

while we moved to visual studio 2013, we were using advanced version of mage.

when I replaced that mage with mage '3.5.30729.1', it worked fine.